# Why is quroum 7 nodes example creating genesis block for every node

Tags: quorum

I tried the Quorum 7 nodes example and it worked flawlesly. but what i found out is that running the `./raft-init.sh` a genesis block is being written for every node.

**Code :**

```
[*] Configuring node 1 (permissioned)
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd1/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=2.896µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd1/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=2.534µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
[*] Configuring node 2 (permissioned)
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [03-07|09:47:20] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd2/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=5.99µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd2/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=5.137µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
[*] Configuring node 3 (permissioned)
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd3/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=1.706µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/ronin/Desktop/testQuorum/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd3/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=2.491µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [03-07|09:47:21] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                                                               hash=c23b4e…8b1b71
```

As you can see `Writing genesis block` is being done for every node. So does everynode has a blockchain on its own ? isn't the 7 nodes example supposed to show how 7 different nodes with different "Responsibilities" coexist and function with one blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,The reason behind this is Quorum use 7 node ledger with keys path quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/keys. 
But if you see the architecture of Quorum please focus on path 
1. quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd1 
2. quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd2

In above path there is geth nodes with permissioned-nodes.json. See the enode section.This encode is Peers encode ID, which we used generally in ethereum to add peers via GETH chain. 
Ethereum geth provides the archiecture to create private nodes via geth by deciding channel ID .

If you remove this encode from peers the writing of genesis will not be there.

Quorum used istanbul algorithm to decide transaction over network.Thats why for example purpose Quorum team use 7th peers with there respective encode share to each other.

Hope you will get my point.